# PDFBOX - Combining PDF UA into ON Large File - PDF UA Tags get nested

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

when I use the PDFBOX and the PDFMergeUtility with either appendDocument or mergeDocuments, I noticed
the the Tag Structure of each individual document is nested under . If I merge 7 documents, it appears the  tag is nested under another  7 times. Is this by design ? Is there away to merge the documents so the  tags are flattened and not nested ? The reason for merging the document is to eventually load the document into a content management using PPD and the Content Management will allow the user to retrieve each document separately. THe JAWS reader can still read the document but I noticed the Document Tags are nested heavily and could cause a performance issue.

Comment: Don't write essays in question, just provide code snippets along with which artifacts/libraries you've used.

Comment: Yes it's by design. If you're unhappy, the best would be you create a JIRA issue with at least two source files, show what you get as result with PDFBox and provide a different result PDF to explain what you expected. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/PDFBOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFBox version 2.0.24 (released in June 2021) has an improved ordering, similar to what Adobe is doing. This was discussed in [PDFBOX-5198](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5198).